# How to send custom form deatils to admin mail in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, php, magento2.4

I have created a custom form in my custom module where can the user enter details like name, email, postcode, etc. Once the user submits the form I need to send the user entered details to `admin@gmail.com`.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look at `Magento_Contact` core module, which does almost the same.

[Frontend controller](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Contact/Controller/Index/Post.php#L69-L91): `\Magento\Contact\Controller\Index\Post::execute`

[Mail sender service](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/app/code/Magento/Contact/Model/Mail.php#L63-L88): `\Magento\Contact\Model\Mail::send`

Comment: Hi @Max,thanks for your answer. how can i add my mail address instead of admin mail. So i can know it is working fine